# Что добавить в код, чтобы добиться корректного отображения заявок

Tags: php, кодировка

Коллеги, добрый день.
Не могли бы помочь, заявки которые приходят с сайта, отображаются как кракозябры. Почта приходит на Outlook.
Понимаю, что косяк в кодировке и нужно прописать кодировку в скрипт. Проблема в том, что нет опыта в программировании на php.

Подскажите, какой код и куда добавить, чтобы письма отображались в человеко-понятной форме.

Спасибо.

```
<?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
    $message = "";

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
        if ( $value !== '') {
            $message .= $key.': '.$value."\n";
        }
    }

    mail('blabla@blabla.ru','Заявка с сайта', $message);

    echo 'OK';
}
?>
```

Comment: Вот полный код <?php
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST" && $_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH'] == 'XMLHttpRequest') {
 $message = "";

 foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  if ( $value !== '') {
   $message .= $key.': '.$value."\n";
  }
 }

 mail('bla@bla.ru','Заявка с сайта', $message);
 //mail('bla@bla.ru','Заявка с сайта', $message);

 echo 'OK';
}
?>

Answer (score 0):

Если исходники сайта в UTF кодировке то нужно Outlook настроить на работу с этой кодировкой. Outlook старая программа там по умолчанию используется кодировка windows.

или использовать функцию [iconv](http://www.php.su/iconv())

**но я бы поступил первым способом**.

Comment: `то нужно Outlook настроить на работу с этой кодировкой.` заголовки нужно настроить в письме, а не аутлук.

Comment: а разве ф-я mail не добавит в заголовок что это utf?

Comment: Так у функции mail() четвертым параметром как раз заголовки указываться должны. Вот, например, решение для UTF-8 http://php.net/manual/ru/function.mail.php#108669 И даже кодировка win-1251 кодируется через base64, глянул сейчас в почтовую программу ;)

Comment: 1. этот параметр не обязательный, если его не указывать его значение автоматически примет кодировку исходника. 2. если он укажет win кодировку принудительно в нем  то он свой же баг получит в других почтовых клиентах. 3. не стоит ориентироваться на стандарты microsoft

Comment: Зачем же тогда люди мучаются и дописываю в заголовки кодировку письма принудительно, если она там сама выставляется?

Comment: Ну заголовки это не заголовок туда можно закладывать много дополнительной информации. Плюс к этому можно сказать что если бы указание кодировки было бы критическим то это стало бы обязательным параметром.

Comment: Все-таки mail() кроме двух заголовков `To:` и `Subject:` ни чего не формирует, если не указан четвертый параметр функции с доп. заголовками. Подтверждение в тестах https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/1c295d4a9ac78fcc2f77d6695987598bb7abcb83/ext/standard/tests/mail/mail_basic.phpt и в этой статье https://www.netangels.ru/support/hosting-howto/php-mail/ `На самом деле функция mail() просто формирует строку следующего вида: $additional_headers To: $to Subject: $subject $message а затем передает ее на обработку стандартной UNIX'овой команде отправки почты, ...`

Comment: вот этих двух заголовков достаточно для доставки письма клиенту, остальные обработки (дополнительные заголовки) перекладываются во внешние обработки.